# Swift Unable To Convert NSString To JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I am using a `WKUserScript` for communications between a `UIWebView` and a server. This particular code will allow user's to search for geographical places. I receive a message back just fine in the function

```
func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController,
    didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage)
```

The variable `message` has an `AnyObject` body. That value I want to convert to a `JSONObject` so I can access it's contents. Here is the `message.body`:

```
{
    "status":"OK",
    "predictions":[
        {
            "description":"Dallas, TX, United States",
            "id":"fa589a36153613fc17b0ebaebbea7c1e31ca62f0",
            "matched_substrings":[{"length":6,"offset":0}],
            "place_id":"ChIJS5dFe_cZTIYRj2dH9qSb7Lk",
            "reference":"CkQxAAAAJNbPZRkdsyxuKT4FzFmgpBx9HWnZLNhxprRQB0zy62sHCXo3tkHfV_M5dK4Cabp2KL43nIKAAyrv_RI4qbvNfRIQ1dzEGuqywMIAlNg_1AKvoRoUQN32C2uNo4KzZ9j58lB-wjPpjJw",
            "terms":[
                {"offset":0,"value":"Dallas"},
                {"offset":8,"value":"TX"},
                {"offset":12,"value":"United States"}
            ],
        "types":["locality","political","geocode"]},
        {
            "description":"Dallas Athletic Club Drive, Dallas, TX, United States",
            "id":"37c4f8d416b9d3975ad57662eb022a0d410e8f76",
            "matched_substrings":[{"length":6,"offset":0}],
            "place_id":"EjVEYWxsYXMgQXRobGV0aWMgQ2x1YiBEcml2ZSwgRGFsbGFzLCBUWCwgVW5pdGVkIFN0YXRlcw",
            "reference":"CkQ5AAAArHSWkIVO6uTH4qE6LxRHshWAfgSnMfxXiBxqf_ZO3O-xQ8RIKKHA9QT7LKwf6Ic788Bzy_I2FpemvcQhE6o5ZRIQ5td4XsjIiyX6D6_dgI3YIxoURu_oROPuOguuorK3Tw11veN7XJI",
            "terms":[
                {"offset":0,"value":"Dallas Athletic Club Drive"},
                {"offset":28,"value":"Dallas"},
                {"offset":36,"value":"TX"},
                {"offset":40,"value":"United States"}
            ],
            "types":["route","geocode"]
        }
    ]
}
```

The `JSONObject` has a status, which lets me know if the results are valid or if an error occurred. I am using `SwiftyJSON` to create and access my `JSON`s. I create the `JSONObject`:

```
let json = JSON(message.body as! NSString)
```

and I attempt to access the status key like:

```
if let status = json["status"].string {
    print("status: \(status)")
}
```

But I am no able to reach the print statement. I have noticed that `NSDictionary` and `JSON` have new line characters when you print them out to the console, but I didn't think that would make a difference. Does anyone know why I am unable to retrieve the status variable from the `JSON`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't initalize a SwiftyJSON object directly with a string, you have to convert this string to data (or use the data you got in the first place if that's the case).

Assuming `message.body` is a string:

```
if let dataFromString = message.body.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
    let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)
    if let status = json["status"].string {
        print("status: \(status)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I was thinking you could do that.